# Displaying an XML file in more than one web page

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that I would like to display on two separate web pages, with two different stylesheets. The problem is that the stylesheet is specified in the XML file, which usually rules this out. I have tried to work around this by splitting of the data from the transformation itself, and including it as a separate file. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="news.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY items SYSTEM "news_items.xml">
]>
<wrapper>
&items;
</wrapper>
```

Here news_items.xml is a pure XML file with no headers, and a single root node, something like this:

```
<items>
  <item>
    ---
  </item>
  <item>
    ---
  </item>
  <item>
    ---
  </item>
</items>
```

The stylesheet news.xsl iterates over the repeating node, and produces nicely formatted output. This arrangement allows me to repeat the exercise with a different stylesheet, without duplicating the data. It works on Chrome, but not on IE or any of the webkit browsers that I am targeting.

Is there a better way to do this? I would like to be able to use a single XML file as the contents are fairly dynamic.

**Later:** I actually solved this problem on the server side, using the PHP XSLTProcessor class. This was not an option under the terms of the question as it was posed, and for that I apologise. This is not an area that I am particularly familiar with, and I am not really competent to award the bounty to anyone, even if they have submitted a perfect solution. Sorry about that.

Comment: The xi:include tag seems to fail in all browsers.

Comment: Do you have control of the XML at all or not? If you do, you could collapse the two XSLs into one with a simple root level XML attribute.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dummy XML file without actual data that contains the stylesheet call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="YOUR_STYLESHEET.xsl"?>
<root/>
```

The stylesheet itself doesn't use the dummy data but gets the real data via "document()":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('YOUR_DATA_FILE.xml')/YOUR_XPATH"/>
  </xsl:template>
  ...use templates to do something...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize the XSLT template, and based on the XSLT parameter, you can apply this or that template (`xsl:call-template`).

```
<xsl:param name="style" select="defaultStyle"/>

<xsl:template name="adjustStyle" match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$style = 'defaultStyle'">
            <xsl:call-template ...>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template ...>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet, but this is in response to your question in the comments.

If you have access to the style sheets, you can use `<xsl:template match="<INSTERT ELEMENT HERE">` to specify styling to specific parts of your xml file. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp) is some documentation. That way, you don't need to include a separate file, just make several templates within the same XSL file.

Answer (score 0):

1)For the same xml have different stylesheets, so  it becomes

```
<html>
<head>
link to your conditional stylesheet
</head>
<body>
Your transformed html from xml that remains same in both conditions
</body>
```

2)Generate different output using conditions:-

```
 <xsl:if test="your condition in xml">
```